# Keep RFT script resources in the same folder as the script

Tags: rft

RFT keeps a script's resources in a special folder called resources.

Is there a way to tell RFT to keep these files together with the script file in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such option available. and for existing if somehow we manage to do it the new assets/resources will again end up in the same resources folder.
What is your requirement though?

Comment: We want to use TFS eclipse plugin in RFT to be able to keep our scripts and datapools in TFS. One of the options is to keep each script and its resources in a separate folder and check-in/out the folder using the TFS plugin.

Comment: okay , I got your point.. How about  check in/out  the project folder and adding the unwanted items/files  as  ignored resources ( I m not sure if TFS has that  option though) .    But in RFT  there is no mechanism (as per my knowledge ) for having the resources along with the script.

Comment: Checking out the entire project is cumbersome for the users, as later it is hard to remember which files to check-in. Checking in all the project checks-in unrelated modified files. So we are looking for a solution to extend TFS plugin..